# Android material design replicate toolbar breadcrumbs example

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to replicate the breadcrumbs example:

[image]

I've gotten as far as adding TextViews to the Toolbar but can't fully replicate the font/size/color of the Toolbar's style and can't get the breadcrumbs to float off the screen to the left.

Comment: Do you have a link to where the specification is for the breadcrumb is? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own Breadcrumb View and add it in your Toolbar. Maybe based on the now deprecated [FragmentBreadCrumbs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html) view.

To get the breadcrumbs to float off the screen you can use negative margin.